# Convert md5 hash into png files with python

Tags: python, md5, md5-file

I download FCCM 100M dataset as md5 hash files. I want to convert them to pictures again, I have a text file with a bunch of hash ids. The file goes like:

```
f5d2d5ebbd55342117fe266731baf2a5
6a452a9fafd6ec7f03c1b8c211ce21
555ce54ec5c04af010e448b879ca3a6
222bd82f713e946402485c12289424b
8b81e1c955d953ee3786ceee31caa134
f18cd1ce5cbe3775a3e3b1ee8589bc7
44d0957ef8d7396fb3a52b49d922b2
94db11aa5551f2a4eebdb2fd2faebc9a
f3d37ee62f52f8593cb4e7e38e5c6fa9
9175211ad12b838eb5a5fdc2fe393775
e164c4280aaccd198c8e8983163262a
94ea8b6f281adf69a9dfe8393399e457
e25a23b0f82dddbd9e19dee8a40da
6556584ecd55e67cea03be366578934
dc4040e91772dfc6f965ed8d8d2d5a9b
```

How can I convert them back to pictures? In the internet mostly they tell how you convert images to md5 file but there's no explanation how you can convert them back.

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: _"there's no explanation how you can convert them back"_ Because you can't. Converting a hash into a file is a brute-force operation of trying every single combination of bits until you find a combination that has the same hash. And then you can't be sure that the file is actually correct, because there's an infinite number of files with the same hash. Hashing is a one-way operation.

Comment: Using a cryptographic hash algorithms is some referred to as "one-way encryption". There is no way back. You will need to get the actual image files.